# W3C Geolocation API - Will use GPS of mobile device?

Tags: android, mobile, geolocation, gps

I have a question about the Geolocation API. If you ask the location on a mobile website visited by for example an android smartphone? Will it use the GPS from the smartphone to get the location or not?

I know with native apps it will use the GPS from the smartphone but also on the web?

Greetings
Niels

I found this on the developers google site :

Geolocation refers to the identification of the geographic location of a user or computing device via a variety of data collection mechanisms. Typically, most geolocation services use network routing addresses or **internal GPS devices** to determine this location. Note that geolocation is a device-specific API; some browser/devices support it, while others do not (or cannot), so you cannot assume that geolocation is always possible for a web application.
*Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation?hl=nl*

So I think it uses the gps if it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geolocation refers to the identification of the geographic location of a user or computing device via a variety of data collection mechanisms. Typically, most geolocation services use network routing addresses or internal GPS devices to determine this location. Note that geolocation is a device-specific API; some browser/devices support it, while others do not (or cannot), so you cannot assume that geolocation is always possible for a web application.
Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation?hl=nl

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as you allow it in Android geolocation settings.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on the browser and the permissions said browser receives from the user / system. Most common android browsers should use the native geolocation, which is probably more than only GPS by itself.

Test it for yourself on your target devices to go sure. Sometimes a WLAN can screw up the geolocation.